# NSTextView: Get text changes (insertions and deletions)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I've got an `NSTextView` and I get the `-textDidChange:` notification. From that, I can get the current string value of the whole textview, but I can't figure out how to tell what's been deleted and added.

For example, if the string in the text view  was `This is a string` and the user deleted the `g`, how can I be made aware of that change?

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably without subclassing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) that should do what you are looking for:

```
– textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:
– textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:
– textView:shouldChangeTypingAttributes:toAttributes:
– textViewDidChangeTypingAttributes:
```

Comment: I saw these but I was confused (the first 3 at least), because they are `BOOL` methods. It confused me because I wasn't sure exactly what to do here. The text change hasn't been committed by this point, correct?

Comment: You have to return a BOOL after you do whatever it is you need to do. You probably just want to return YES unless you want to forbid certain changes.

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I've been doing. I'm just unsure if this was a place to do a lot of work (I'm trying to do some syntax assist, like automatically inserting or deleting characters depending on what's inserted or deleted).

Comment: If you don't want to subclass, then this is where you should do it.